# Defining type of binary file string

Tags: python, string, binary, binaryfiles, file-type

Is it possible to check what type of data does represent string binary file?

For example:
We have binary data read from image file (f.e. example.jpg). Can we guess that this binary data represent image file? If yes, how we can do that?

Comment: magic numbers typically identify the type of file ...  its usually the first n bytes of a file ...

Comment: Are you just trying to distinguish the type of image files among a few specific types (JFIF, PNG, TIFF, etc.), or the file of any file at all, with no restrictions? If you stick to something specific, you can get more specific answers (e.g., distinguish animated GIFs from multi-image poster GIFs, or TIFF with JPEG compression from TIFF with RLE compression, or whatever), and with more confidence. If it just has to work with "almost everything", you can only get pretty good answers—in which case, @Xymostech has the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) library. It seems to do what you want (although I've never used it myself).

Comment: +1. I actually have used it, and it works great. Or, at least, as well as the Unix `file` command, which is about as well as _anything_ general-purpose is going to work.